# Android Studio 3.0 Error. Migrate dependency configurations for local modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I recently installed the latest Canary build of Android Studio which is currently using the Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha4 .

I now get a error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :MyLib.
Required by:
project :app
```

I has read: [Migrate dependency configurations for local modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_dependencies)

> ```
> dependencies 
>
> {
>
> // This is the old method and no longer works for local
> // library modules:
> // debugCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'debug')
> // releaseCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'release')
>
> // Instead, simply use the following to take advantage of
> // variant-aware dependency resolution. You can learn more about
> // the 'implementation' configuration in the section about
> // new dependency configurations.
> implementation project(':foo')
>
> // You can, however, keep using variant-specific configurations when
> // targeting external dependencies. The following line adds 'app-magic'
> // as a dependency to only the 'debug' version of your module.
>
> debugImplementation 'com.example.android:app-magic:12.3' 
> }
> ```

I changed:

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':MyLib', configuration: 'appReleaseApp')
debugCompile project(path: ':MyLib', configuration: 'appDebug')
```

to:

```
implementation project(':MyLib')
```

but i still have this error: `Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :MyLib.`

lib gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        releaseApp {
            ...
        }
        releaseSdk {
            ...'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1{
            ...
        flavor2{
            ...
        }
        flavor3{
            ...
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
        }
    }
}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 12
        versionName "5.0.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            ...
        }

        flavor2 {
            ...
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                jvmArgs '-noverify'
                systemProperty 'robolectric.logging.enable', true
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    //    releaseCompile project(path: ':MyLib', configuration: 'appRelease')
    //    debugCompile project(path: ':MyLib', configuration: 'appDebug')
    implementation project(':MyLib')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'

    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help

Comment: Have you replaced all dependencies inside MyLib? compile -> api, provided -> compileOnly. and compile -> implementation in app module (for all other dependencies). Truth to be told, compile and provided are still supported, not sure if it helps. I've upgraded gradle plugin this morning and it worked with setting above.

Comment: i replaced compile -> api, still i'm getting same error. If i even just remove all dependencies in MyLib, app still could not resolve project :MyLib

Comment: Maybe It'd help if you could post both gradle files, hard to guess on blind.
I have also removed retrolambda, increased sourceCompatibility to java8..

Comment: i don't use retrolambda...

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Same issue. Unable to proceed further

Comment: how to solve this ? any idea ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Google added more instruction how to solve it: [Resolve build errors related to dependency matching](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#resolve_matching_errors)

Cause of build error:

**Your app includes a build type that a library dependency does not.**

> For example, your app includes a "staging" build type, but a
>   dependency includes only a "debug" and "release" build type.
>
> Note that there is no issue when a library dependency includes a build
>   type that your app does not. That's because the plugin simply never
>   requests that build type from the dependency.

**Resolution**

Use matchingFallbacks to specify alternative matches for a given build type, as shown below:

```
// In the app's build.gradle file.
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        release {}
        staging {
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback build types that the
            // plugin should try to use when a dependency does not include a
            // "staging" build type. You may specify as many fallbacks as you
            // like, and the plugin selects the first build type that's
            // available in the dependency.
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'qa', 'release']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up brother for explanation

Answer (score 37):

After facing the same issue, I finally declared exactly the same buildTypes in both App and Modules' build.gradle files.

In your case, adding

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp {}
    releaseSdk {}
}
```

to your module's build.gradle should do the trick.

Be sure to change any "compile project" to "implementation project" too.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is the correct answer. Because the new plugin automatically matches build types they must exactly matching types in each module. I hope the error text will be more precise.

Comment: Where can you read this information? Its so freaking hard to avoid spending  days on gradle issues

Comment: changed everything to 'Implementation' and it still throws same error. Here is my build type for App & library https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dda4a85d4d3c021a8fc07251901f9f2

Comment: As the gradle plugin has been updated from that time, the correct answer should be using the buildTypeMatching now. Look at the response of @kamy below

Comment: Thanks! It seems that all modules have to specify the exact same buildType names.

Comment: Already have only release build type in both app and module's gradle. Still not working

Answer (score 33):

With the new plugin, the variant-aware dependency resolution

```
implementation project(':MyLib')
```

needs to have exact matching build types. [The migration guide describes this](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_dependencies)

> For instance, it is not possible to make a 'debug' variant consume a
> 'release' variant through this mechanism because the producer and
> consumer would not match. (In this case, the name 'debug' refers to
> the published configuration object mentioned above in the Publishing
> Dependencies section.) Now that we publish two configurations, one for
> compiling and one for runtime, this old way of selecting one
> configuration really doesn't work anymore.

So the old method of

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'debug')
```

will not work any more.

### Example

With your example this would look like this:

In app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp {}
        releaseSdk {}
  }
  ...
  dependencies {
    implementation project(':MyLib')
  }
}
```

In module/lib 'MyLib' `build.gradle`:

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp {}
    releaseSdk {}
  }
}
```

Therefore, the build type must *exactly* match, no more no less.

### Using Build-Type Fallbacks

A new feature called "matchingFallbacks" can be used to define default buildtypes if a submodule does not define the buildtype.

> Use matchingFallbacks to specify alternative matches for a given build type (...)

For example if module/lib 'MyLib' gradle would look like this:

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseLib {}
  }
}
```

You could define the following in your app `build.gradle`:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {}
    releaseApp {
        ...
        matchingFallbacks = ['releaseLib']
    }
    releaseSdk {
        ...
        matchingFallbacks = ['releaseLib']
    }
  }
  ...
  dependencies {
    implementation project(':MyLib')
  }
}
```

### Missing Flavor Dimensions

> Use missingDimensionStrategy in the defaultConfig block to specify the
> default flavor the plugin should select from each missing dimension

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        missingDimensionStrategy 'minApi', 'minApi18', 'minApi23'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, Here is my build type for App & library. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dda4a85d4d3c021a8fc07251901f9f2

Comment: flavors should be same as well

Comment: This explanation helped me understand why  a legacy app broke once I upgraded gradle, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I found this migration page:
[Build matching types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#buildTypeMatching)

It states:

> **Select defaults for missing build types**
>   If a consumer configures a build type that a producer does not, you need to manually match the consumer's build type to one from the producer. For example, if your app module configures a "staging" build type and its library module dependency, "mylibrary", does not, the Android plugin throws the following build error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
Required by: project :app
```

> To resolve this error, you need to specify which build type from "mylibrary" the Android plugin should match to the app's "staging" build type. You can do this with the buildTypeMatching property in the app's build.gradle file, as shown below:

```
// Add the following to the consumer's build.gradle file.
android {
    ...
    // Tells the Android plugin to use a library's 'debug' build type
    // when a 'staging' build type is not available. You can include
    // additional build types, and the plugin matches 'staging' to the
    // first build type it finds from the one's you specify. That is,
    // if 'mylibrary' doesn't include a 'debug' build type either, the
    // plugin matches 'staging' with the producer's 'release' build type.
    buildTypeMatching 'staging', 'debug', 'release'
}
```

Adding buildTypeMatching fixed it for me without creating unecessary types in my library

Answer (score 0):

Today I also had the same problem after migrating to Android Studio 3.
The problem is the gradle is not able to resolve the certain libraries due to network issue. The reasons might be various.
If you work behind the proxy you need to add the proxy parameters in gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<proxy_port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
```

In my case I had one more issue. My company uses the self signed SSL certificate so the SSL connection had some problem. If same applies also for you, you can set the parameter again in gradle.properties file as follows:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

To be more clear you can click on "Show details" link in messages log in Android Studio. This log will be more helpful to decide what is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2. Android Gradle plugin 3.1.2. Gradle 4.4. I have a library module with flavours such as `trial` and `premium`. As part of the process of migrating to the Android Gradle plugin 3.1.2 I added a flavour dimension of `main` to my library module's gradle build file. To correct the build error therefore in my app's `build.gradle` file I changed the following:

```
debugImplementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'premiumDebug')
releaseImplementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'premiumRelease')
```

became

```
implementation project(':library')
```

and I added the following line to my `defaultConfig` block: `missingDimensionStrategy 'main', 'premium'`