# Android Studio 3.0 - Unable to resolve local dependency error

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my Android Studio to version 3.0, and subsequently updated Gradle to version 4.1.

Now, after I try to load my existing project I get the following errors:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@UnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :intro-slider-lib.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@UnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :intro-slider-lib.

I've tried several solutions posted in other threads, but none seems to work. Here's my **build.gradle (app)** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects{
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {}
        ApkQuipons {}
        staging {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'qa', 'release']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation project(':intro-slider-lib')
}
```

EDIT: Here's my **build.gradle (project)** code as well:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@UnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :intro-slider-lib.

**Don't**

```
implementation project(':intro-slider-lib')
```

**Do**

```
 compile project(':intro-slider-lib')
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`**.

**EDIT**

If you want to use **`implementation`**, then set

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Read [**`difference between implementation and compile in gradle`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the way I had it written before, got the same problem.

Comment: @McNeto `compileSdkVersion 26` .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390590/android-studio-3-0-error-migrate-dependency-configurations-for-local-modules

Comment: As you said, I added the classpath to my code and now I'm getting the error "The project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0)."

Comment: @McNeto for test case set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`

Comment: Same thing happens

Comment: @McNeto read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compilecla

Comment: Wasn't able to solve it, ended up reverting to Android Studio 2.3.3 because I really needed to make a successful build.

Comment: @McNeto use `build:gradle:2.3.3`